# Placing DataView and ListView together on the same Panel

Tags: listview, layout, panel, containers, dataview

I am having a problem with designing user interface for developing app by using sencha touch, first off, I am familiar with iPhone interface builder which was easy to place whatever I need on the screen by just dragging and dropping objects but now I have to deal with hard coding just for designing interface specifically my problem is to put data view which got XTemplate, over the list view separately so that when I want to scroll it down I can see the list view but with my code I scroll the data view down and not seeing list view cuz they acting like they are separate from each other they both have their own scrolling feature :) if I open the app with browser which has enough space to show everything.. I can the either see the list view and the data view so any ideas could be very helpful cuz it is time restrictive project and I already waste a lot of time focusing on it.. you can see my code below Thx

```
this.listpanel = new Ext.Panel({
    layout:'fit',
        items: [symbolView,newsBySymbolList],
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: this.record.data.c,
            items: [{
                    ui: 'back',
                    text: 'Back',
                    scope: this,
                    handler: function(){
                        this.ownerCt.setActiveItem(this.prevCard, {
                            type: 'slide',
                            reverse: true,
                            scope: this,
                            after: function(){
                                this.destroy();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                ]   
        }],
        listeners: {
            activate: { fn: function(){
                newsBySymbolList.getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
                Ext.repaint();
            }, scope: this }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use layout:fit. You need to use following on containing panel

```
layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
scrollable: true,
```

then for each subview set:

```
flex:1, 
scrollable: false,
```

That should do it.